# What cardinality is this preimage?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

What is  $\mid F^{-1}[\{ \mathbb{N} \}]$, with $F: \mathbb{N^{\mathbb{N}}} \times (\mathcal{P(\mathbb{N}) \backslash} \{ \emptyset \}) \longrightarrow \mathcal{P(\mathbb{N})}$ given by:
$$F(f, A) = f[A] \cap f^{-1}[A]$$

By definition 
$$F^{-1}[\{ \mathbb{N} \}] = \{ (f, A) \in \mathbb{N^{\mathbb{N}}} \times (\mathcal{P(\mathbb{N}) \backslash} \{ \emptyset \}) : F(f,A) \in {\mathbb{\{N\}}} \}$$

It loks to me like all the ordered pairs $(f, A)$ that we are looking for are of the form $(f, \mathbb{N})$, because if $A \neq \mathbb{N}$, then either $f[A] \neq \mathbb{N}$ or $f^{-1}[A] \neq \mathbb{N}$, but I don't have proof for that. But even if that was the case then I still don't see the cardinality, or how to approach the proof.

Comment: Is this an insanely complicated way of asking how many functions from $\Bbb N$ to itself are surjective?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. Why would it be that?

Comment: I suspect understanding *why* this observation is true is a good chunk of this exercise. You can start by verifying that every surjective function is in this preimage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does indeed reduce to counting surjective functions from $\mathbb N$ to itself. This is because of the following reasoning:

First, note that the set $F^{-1}(\mathbb N)$ is the set of pairs $(f, A)$ that satisfy $f(A)=\mathbb N , f^{-1}(A) = \mathbb N$.

This implies that $f$ is surjective, that is, $f(\mathbb N) = \mathbb N$.

Then, recall that for any $f$ and $A \subseteq \text{Im} f$, $f\left (f^{-1}(A)\right ) = A$. However, $f^{-1}(A) = \mathbb N$ in our case, so this becomes $f(\mathbb N ) = A$, and since $f$ is surjective, $A=\mathbb N$.

Therefore, any pair in $F^{-1}(\mathbb N)$ must be of the form $(f\ \text{surjective}, \mathbb N)$. It is trivial to see that all pairs of that form are in $F^{-1}(\mathbb N)$, which proves:
$$ F^{-1}(\mathbb N) = \{(f\ \text{surjective}, \mathbb N)\} $$

It is known that the set of surjective functions from $N$ to itself has the cardinality of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is not true that for every $f$ $f(f^{-1}(A) ) = A$, that's true only if $f$ is surjective, otherwise we only have that  $f(f^{-1}(A)) \subseteq A$.

Comment: @Naah You are right. $A$ needs to be in the image of $f$.